# jQuery stop animation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this spinning div and I want it to stop when I click on a button by using the [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method, but for some reason it doesn't work. I hope you can shed some light on this issue for me.

Here is a snippet which performs the animation and demonstrates that the `Stop animation` button does not stop the animation.

```js
$('button').bind('click', function(){
    $('.player-disc').stop(true, false);
});
```

```css
#player {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #E25822;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
#player .player-disc {
  -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#player .player-disc span {
  position: absolute;
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Stop animation</button>
<div id="player">
  <div class="player-disc">
  <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried any other combinations of `.stop(false, false)` etc.

a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71y9syuu/)

Comment: Your issue is that you think that jQuery's [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) is effective on *all* animations, no matter how the animation is performed. jQuery's `.stop()` works to stop animations which were started by jQuery methods, not all methods in existence.  To stop the animation, you will need to affect whatever method of performing the animation was used. In your specific case, there are a variety of methods, as is being demonstrated by the answers you are getting.

Comment: I moved your code from JSFiddle into the question. For debugging questions you must include a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Without enough code to duplicate the problem, the question is considered off-topic and subject to closure for that reason. Another time, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS issues try using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). If it is possible to get your code working in one it makes it much easier for people to see what the issue is and provide tested, working solutions in their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, it's CSS animation.

To stop it and reset disc to its original position use (this also resets animation):

```
$('.player-disc').css('animation', 'none');
```

To pause it and not reset disc to its original position use:

```
$('.player-disc').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
```

You can then resume animation using:

```
$('.player-disc').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
```

```js
$('#btn1').bind('click', function(){
    $('.player-disc').css('animation', 'none');
});
$('#btn2').bind('click', function(){
    $('.player-disc').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
});
$('#btn3').bind('click', function(){
    $('.player-disc').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
});
```

```css
#player {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #E25822;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
#player .player-disc {
  -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#player .player-disc span {
  position: absolute;
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" type="button">Set animation to none</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button">Pause animation</button>
<button id="btn3" type="button">Play animation</button>
<div id="player">
  <div class="player-disc">
  <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a CSS animation, not a jQuery animation so you just need to set the css `animation` property to `"none"`:

```
$('.player-disc').css('animation', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your animation is being initialised in the CSS. Therefore you must stop it by CSS. `$(".player-disc").css("animation-play-state", "paused");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
 $("button").click(function(){
$('.player-disc').css('animation', 'none');
 });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71y9syuu/3/)