# How to resume the animation after it has been suspended in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to know if there is a way of resuming the animation after it has been suspended. When i click the animation button after it has been paused the animation start again from scratch.I want to resume from the last position the rectangle.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {
  selection: false
});

let isPlaying = false;

document.getElementById('animateBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  playPause();
});

function playPause() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    document.getElementById('animateBtn').innerText = 'Play';
    pauseAnimation().then(() => {
      console.log('animation paused');
    });
  } else {
     document.getElementById('animateBtn').innerText = 'Pause';
    startAnimation().then(() => {
      isPlaying = false;
      console.log('animation finished');
    });
  }
}

async function pauseAnimation() {
  isPlaying = false;
}

async function startAnimation() {
  isPlaying = true;
  const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: '#aaf',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: '#faa',
    selectable: false
  });
  canvas.add(rect);
  await animateRect(rect);

}

function animateRect(rect) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    rect.animate({
      left: 400,
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      onComplete: function() {
        resolve();
      },
      abort: function() {
          return !isPlaying;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
<button id="animateBtn">Animate</button>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There are methods to stop animations. But there's no actual animation going on in your `getImage()` function.

Comment: For instance, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296791/jquery-stop-animation-method for stopping CSS animations.

Comment: I made some clarification with my post, The animation is actually done with the help of a library called fabric js

Comment: Did you ever find out a way to do this?